# Maintaining colours of a png texture coloured three.is obj

Tags: three.js, transparency, alpha, blending

I have a obj of a T-shirt and png that has different colours. When I apply the png as a texture to the T-shirt mesh, the ones colours show up on lighter colours like white or yellow. But on blue or red T-shirt colours the png shows up black.

I assume that this is because of the blending mode however I haven’t been able to get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I’ve tried different blending modes and I’ve tried making the material of the T-shirt transparent but then the png is also transparent.

I am very new to three.ja